# How to pass two presets arguments to babel without using .babelrc file?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

for some reason i don't want to use .babelrc file.

presets argument can be pass to babel-cli like

```
babel --presets react
```

but getting error "es2015 doesn't exist"
 whenever I try to pass two presets parameter using

`babel --presets react es2015`

is there a way to paass two or more presets to babel-cli without using .babelrc file

Comment: Did you try `--presets=react,es2015`?

Comment: why don't you post it as answer so that I could mark it as answer ? Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @Felix Kling's comment so that this has more visibility than the only answer for this question here at the moment.

> Did you try --presets=react,es2015?

Answer (score 1):

If you use npm:

- Install presets and babel-cli:

  `npm install babel-cli babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save-dev`
- Tell Babel to use it in `package.json` instead of .babelrc:

```
    ...
    "babel": {
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
      ]
    },
    ...
```